# How to create pass through Task.ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I want to tack on a task at the end of an original task, but would like to preserve the original result and type. The appended task is just for logging purpose, such as writing to console, etc. For example:

```
Task.Run(() => DateTime.Now.Hour > 12 ? "Hey!" : throw new Exception())
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
            return t.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
            throw t.Exception;
        }
    });
```

The type of the original task is `Task<string>`. Here I `return t.Result` if the task doesn't encounter error, and I `throw t.Exception` in case the task encounters error. Looks like the type remains `Task<string>` but not sure about the exception side.

Is this the right way to do it? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to rethrow the exception. The task will throw `AggregrateException` and you can get the real exceptions with `InnerExceptions` property to handle them.

For logging, you can separate success and failure using [`TaskContinuationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.105).aspx):

```
var t = Task.Run(() => DateTime.Now.Hour > 12 ? "Hey!" : throw new Exception());

t.ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Success"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

t.ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Faiure"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

The success will be logged only if task executed successfully until the end. And failure will be logged if there was an unhandled exception.

This separates logging and getting the result. So you can just get the result from the first task.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution to this problem is to return the `t` itself, resulting in a continuation of type `Task<Task<string>>`, and then [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) it to get a `Task<string>`:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return DateTime.Now.Hour > 12 ? "Hey!" : throw new Exception();
});

Task<string> continuation = task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Success: {t.Result}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failure or Cancellation");
    }
    return t;
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
    .Unwrap();
```

This approach guarantees that all the errors of the original `task` will be propagated through the `continuation`, or, if the `task` is canceled, that the `continuation` will be also canceled with the same `CancellationToken` stored inside it.

In the vast majority of cases the tasks fail with only one error¹, so it's simpler to use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) instead of the cumbersome [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method:

```
async Task<T> OnCompletionLog<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    try
    {
        T result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Success: {t.Result}");
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failure or Cancellation");
        throw;
    }
}

Task<string> continuation = OnCompletionLog(task);
```

¹ <sub>AFAIK the tasks that can fail with more than one error are the `Task.WhenAll`, the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, and the `IDataflowBlock.Completion`.</sub>